# Thingsboard service: How do I change the source code?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, thingsboard

I have installed Thingsboard PE in a Ubuntu server [as a service](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/ubuntu/).

My question is if I can still manage to change the source code and how, or if I do have to make a clean install from the git repo.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for ThingsBoard CE, since it includes features like RBAC and Integrations which aren't completely open source. Therefore you need to stick to official builds by ThingsBoard Dev team.

But you could still extend the platform by adding custom integrations, rule nodes or widgets:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/contribution/how-to-contribute-your-device-integration-guide/
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/contribution/rule-node-development/
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/